# Facebook like button not working when multiple instances loaded in php page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a VERY weird problem with the Facebook like button not working when multiple buttons are loaded in a php page

I uploaded a test page that shows the issue at http://www.xurvivor.com/test.php

Multiple share+like buttons are loaded; however, most of them show a count of 2, which is wrong. Out of the 23 loaded buttons only 3 show the correct count (two 0's and one 1)

The weird thing is that debugging at the open graph debuggers looks fine

For instance if you try debugging the first button, results are fine:

I stripped most of the code from the original php page to see if I could find the issue, also searching online didn't come up with any solutions for me

Furthermore, if you click on the first share button in the test page I uploaded comes up with the following url:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fxurvivor.com%2Farticle.php%3Fp%3Da-la-ocasioacuten-la-pintan-calva%26d_id%3D4%26l_id%3D1&display=popup

if I run this portion of the url starting after the u= in the open graph debugger, the debugger looks fine to me:

http%3A%2F%2Fxurvivor.com%2Farticle.php%3Fp%3Da-la-ocasioacuten-la-pintan-calva%26d_id%3D4%26l_id%3D1&display=popup

I'm running out of ideas. Hope someone can give me some suggestion on how to fix this issue

Comment: Can you give an example of a URL that have the wrong like count? And what do you mean with wrong count? What is the right one and where do you get that one from?

Comment: go to http://www.xurvivor.com/test.php and you will see all buttons, all have the wrong counts except 3 show the correct count (two 0's and one 1). It's a brand new Facebook account, just one of those should show 1 like, everything else 0

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, in case in the future somebody runs into this, the problem is that Facebook can't deal very well with weird characters like é, í, ó, ú, etc in the url being processed